# Do I have to teach luis.ai what an "employee" is for EVERY intent?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I was actually told this is true, and if so, then I must be missing something. If I make an intent with an `employee` custom entity, then I make another intent that also uses the `employee` entity, do I have to enter all the employees again? One for each intent?

I made an intent called `who-is`. The user basically asks "who is {employee}" or "tell me about {employee}". I entered about 5 different phrases. However, I used a lot of employee names to teach luis what an employee is, so I have the same phrases repeated a lot of times to get all the names. So far so good.

Then I made another intent to get the number of direct reports for an `employee`. Do I have to teach that intent the employee names **again**? If so, this is a hassle and I must be missing something. We may have tens of different intents that need an `employee` and tens of sample employees to teach luis.

Comment: As far as I remember, but I'm not 100% sure, you just have to add a few items of `employee` in your new intent and then it will automatically flag other items. Maybe it needs one training iteration, I can't remember

Comment: If you train entities for some of the intents, then it will automatically pick an entity for next utterance or intent.

Answer (score 0):

In Luis Entity works on whole app, so if you have mapped one entity in one intent and if you have similar words in other intents it will be mapped automatically.